# How to use QuantLib in Xcode on MacOS Ventura

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-construction, quantitative-finance

I have already installed QuantLib using homebrew.

I need guidance regarding how to integrate the QuantLib library in Xcode so that I can build and run codes.

Also will the latest version of clang compiler work?

If not, which will?

[Error I am currently facing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqLkr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You might need more env variables configured try

> ./configure --with-boost-include=/opt/homebrew/include/ 
> --with-boost-lib=/opt/homebrew/lib/ 
> --prefix=${HOME}/local/ 
> CXXFLAGS='-O2 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=$YOUR VERSION'
> LDFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=$YOUR VERSION '

If that doesn't work, see if the other options at this link help `https://www.quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml`

Comment: when I ran the following code I faced another error: './configure --with-boost-include=/opt/homebrew/include/ \
            --with-boost-lib=/opt/homebrew/lib/ \
            --prefix=${HOME}/local/ \
            CXXFLAGS='-O2 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=13.4' \
            LDFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=13.4'

zsh: no such file or directory: ./configure' 
I followed the instructions on the quantile website too but still ran into the same issue please provide suggestions.Thanks